# Empty object after filtering with %in%

Tags: r

I am trying to filter one column of a dataframe by a separate object. Every try returns 0 obs in the resulting object, and I really cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

Can someone please help me or offer a better solution?

To make sense of the example, I am trying to filter the ID column in tib by the list of IDs in D, and create a new subset from the result. The code is working but keeps giving me 0

```
ID <- rep(LETTERS, length.out = 21, each = 3)
 w <- sample (1:100, 21)
 d <- c("D", "E")

tib <- tibble(ID, w)
  D <- tibble(d)

check <- filter(tib, ID %in% D)
```

Comment: You've got to reference the column, not the dataset - `filter(tib, ID %in% D$d)`

Comment: Or `right_join(tib, D, join_by(ID == d))`

Comment: @JonSpring - probably makes more sense to do it as a join as it avoids mixing base and tidy subsetting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please replace the `D` with `d`

```r
check <- filter(tib, ID%in%d)


# A tibble: 6 × 2
  ID        w
  <chr> <int>
1 D        47
2 D        64
3 D         4
4 E        31
5 E         3
6 E        12
```

Comment: I'm not a fan of this as it's not clear if this is referencing `d` or `tib$d` ?

Comment: No, it's referencing `d`, there is no `tib$d`. `tib` in the code here only has columns `ID` and `w`.

Comment: @user2554330 - I think you just proved my point inadvertently. ;-)

Comment: @thelatemail, huh? There is no ambiguity about what `d` is referring to.. You can use the `.data$` or `.env$` pronouns if it's unclear, but there is only one `d` here..

Comment: @Axeman - in this tiny example, yes, it's unambiguous. But in a large example where you can't be sure what columns `tib` might have ahead of time, you might think you're filtering by `d` in the (global) environment, and then accidentally filter by `tib$d`